# Auto delete query is executed in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm facing issue in Query that was written through normal CakePHP version 2.3.4
The problem occurs rarely [not frequently] - only few row gets auto deleted.

**There is neither any cron nor any action in Controller-file to execute "Delete" command/query.**

But why this auto-deletion is happening is miserable for me till now.

The Table structure is as provided below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bulk_orders` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order_no` (`order_no`)
) EN

GINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16270 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bulk_order_lines` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=34711 ;
```

Auto delete query is executed like below :
Delete from bulk_orders where ID=1234;

Can anybody please help me to find the solution on this?

Comment: you at least have to identify the action that gets executed and deletes the rows for us to help you.

Comment: regarding your edit: I'm not saying you have a `$this->Model->delete` somewhere... I'm saying that something must be triggering the delete, could be an `updateAll` or something like that; but that happens when you execute an action or a cron, and you need to identify which one and post that here, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Is there a (public) action to delete those? /controller_name/delete/ID?

Comment: How do you know that this statement `Delete from bulk_orders where ID=1234;` was executed? Do you have it in a log or are you guessing?

Comment: "updateAll" is used in application in the controller.
"Delete" is also being used, but by providing proper ID within it.
We don't have logs, as it may become heavy in size in PROD.
We have only guess.
Actually the related Orders are disapperaing i.e. Delete is being executed somewhere automatically.

Comment: Your table structure doesn't make sense. A ``bulk_orders`` table with only an ``id`` but a key of field ``order_no``? A ``bulk_order_lines`` with a reference to an ``order_id`` that we don't get to see? This is confusing and you give no hint of either your complete tables or your associations.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.
I assume you have baked your CRUD controller actions and templates via bake?

Usually this is the developers fault then - failure by design.
The HTTP specs are pretty clear about what protocol type to use for modifying the DB: **POST**

Additionally, it should also be secured via auth or some additional measure to avoid abusing.

But using POST here instead of GET prevents BOTs and people with little knowledge of deleting your content - by accident or purpose.

```
$this->Form->postLink()
```

is what you should be using.
And the action itself should contain

```
$this->request->allowMethod('post');
```

etc.

Please confirm that this is what you got in your code already.